# Selenium-Java automation scripts is not working with Latest version of Firefox browser 63.0.1

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

My Selenium java V(3.13.0) script was working well with Firefox v61.0. But after the latest update of Firefox version 63.0.1 it's stopped working.
I have tried following ways but it didn't work out.

1. Downloaded the latest jar of Selenium-Java 3.141.0
2. Downloaded the latest gecko driver (geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64)

Request to share the solution if anyone also face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This combo works for me.

```
@Test
public static void testMF(){
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","./src/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

and my maven reads:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>27.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

I have Firefox Quantum 63.0.1 (64-bit), geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64, Java8.

Comment: As it's mentioned I've tried with Selenium-java 3.141.5 and guava 27.0-jre. The geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64. But still URL is not being opened. However Firefox browser is getting opened but URL is not opened. Web Page says Unable to Connect.

Comment: Well, what was the error you were getting in stack trace?

Comment: Actual code:  public static void main(String[] args) {
  WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","Driver\\geckodriver64bit.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 try {
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  }catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception Occured");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}f

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//www.google.com/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20www.google.com.
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:41'

Comment: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 63.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 19764, moz:profile: C:\Users\PAVANAGRAWAL\AppDa..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}

Comment: Sorry, while copying the code in comment section, it got missed but Actually it was there in source code. "www"


The URL connectivity issue got resolved by FireFox latest version 63.0.3

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue need to use latest gecko driver version 'geckodriver-v0.23.0'. I use 'geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64' and problem is fixed.

Link for latest gecko driver version : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
[I use gecko driver version as per attached image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbTYM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox Version 63.0.3 is working fine with latest Gecko Driver geckodriver-v0.23.0 and Selenium-java 3.141.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to guava-23.0.jar latest jar file, I had same issue which solved (make sure to remove the previous version for same jar file).
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.0